# Counting a part of the speech in a sentence

Tags: functions, syntax, filtering, natural-language

I want to count a number of nouns in a sentence. For that, I'm using `TextStructere` but I don't know how to get tags of each word.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Length @ TextCases[
  "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."
, "Noun"
]
```

> 2

Comment: thanks a lot for your help